# iOS 7 universal background image

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to set up a universal background image (which has some repetitive animation effects) on my app, which was developed for iOS 6 and below. On iOS 6, to do this, I added a `UIImageView` as a subview to the `self.window` view in the `AppDelegate` method. But this does not seem to work in iOS 7 as the `UIViewControllers` seem to have an opaque white background, and they hide the `UIImageView`. Any idea how I can set up such a background throughout the app?

```
self.animatedBGImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_disc.png"]];
[self.window insertSubview: self.animatedBGImage atIndex:0];
self.rotatingBackgroundImage.center = self.window.center;
```

Comment: in general we always add only a `rootViewController` to `self.window`, and we never bother the subviews of the `UIWindow` object.

Answer (score 0):

Either create a new view controller that has that image as a background, and have all your viewControllers be a subclass of that one, or set the background of all you view controllers to be clearcolor. The last last option might mean a performance issue.

Comment: Hmm. That would mean that each viewController would have a new background image. I want the background to be static, as in it shouldn't be affected by navigations and such.